# MS Excel - autofill +1 each x cells

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to add large numbers of rows to an excel file. I want to autofill a column which is formated as following

```
"TEXT"?
```

where `?` is a number that should repeat 19 times before it increases by one.

However, I dont manage to get excel to autofill this cells adequately.

I marked the first 190 cells with the correct values and still it either starts from the beginning when pulling down the marked area or adds 1 to each additional cell.

How to solve this task purposeful? I'm working with excel 2016.

Googling did not help me, as I dont manage to formulate my problem in a more compact manner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a formula, similar to this:
`="TEXT"&INT((ROW()+17)/19)`
(this works if your data starts in 2nd row)

In the formula:

- `/19` is the cycle of your numbering, it grows after each `19` rows
- `ROW()+17` is to set the first value, e.g.

  - if you want numbering to start from 1 in row 2, then
    `(ROW(<2>)+17)/19` = `(2+17)/19` = `1`
  - if your want in row 1000 to start from 15 then
    `(ROW(<1000>)-1000+15*19)/19` = `(1000-1000+15*19)/19` = `15*19/19` = `19`
  - in general, if you want to start from N in row Y, then use
    `(ROW()-Y+N*19)`

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. However my new data starts in row 479643 (the data before follows another logic) and i don't manage to adapt your solution to my case.

Comment: I've added explanation, hope it helps.